# How to print the results of two async tasks on same list?

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-asynctask

Currently I am working on an app which lists the hotels near you. I'm using the google places API web service and it works fine. But I want to print the distance and duration from the current location to the location of each place.

For listing the hotels, I used an asynctask which then parses JSON and prints the results as a list just like the sunshine app of UDACITY.

But I want to print the distance and duration next to each hotel. But for distance, another api has to be used. Can you please help me how is that possible ?

That is, I actually need a function that calculates the distance and duration at the time of creating the final string for list so that it could be appended with each hotel names.

Comment: I think when the list of hotels came in onPost method of async then  then just get hotels from list and calculate the distance and add to adaptor for showing

Comment: You have to merge the result of both sync api on the basis of some id or name of your hotels and after merging inflate your adapter

Comment: But how can I merge ? please help me with some code. I'm not an expert

Answer (score 0):

In Your case you have to call api upto n+1 times
so process data in doInBackground method of your code
Example -

```
private class PrepareDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // call api here and get response here
            response = apiresult();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                // Call api and add distance and append result here for listing
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Set adapter here
    }

}
```

Comment: I will try and inform you :D anyway, thanks for the idea